# wso2 API Manager custom validations for API request input fields

Tags: json, validation, request, wso2

is there any sample code who can help for my below requirement.
i am publishing Rest APIs in WSO2 API Manager , i would like to intercept my own  API input field validations for each API like input parameter format and value etc .If validation success then API Manager should allow the request to invoke back-end , else reject the request with error message.

I have gone though some documents and i understand we can achieve this by adding mediation extensions and custom handler, however I couldn't find any sample code for this.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM140/Adding+a+Mediation+Extension

If we are writing custom handler , should we write it for each API and do config changes in API Synapsis file? 
I would like to have a single handler which will invoke for All APIs, and handler will execute the corresponding method which is applicable for that specific API .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have single custom handler which will be used by all APIs. You can use the latest version of the [API Manager which is 1.9.1](http://wso2.com/api-management/try-it/)

You can extend the API Manager to support any custom authentication mechanism by writing your own authentication handler class. This custom handler must extend `org.apache.synapse.rest.AbstractHandler` class and implement the `handleRequest()` and `handleResponse()` methods.

You can find a sample implementation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/47515531/APIAuthenticationHandler.java?version=1&modificationDate=1438295287000&api=v2). For more details, please have a look on [Writing Custom Handlers](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Writing+Custom+Handlers)

Comment: Thanks Abimaran!! I think this could help me, will try it out and let know .

Comment: @Abhimaran : I tried with the above option and i could see custom handler is getting invoke for all APIs, however i am unable to get the JSON payload/input parameters for POST request. could you please let me know how to get input parameters using MessageContest object.                  I understand WSO2 AM will convert the JSON request to xml and once invoking the actual back end rest service WSO2 AM will again convert from xml to JSON.

Comment: did you get any response ? how to send the post request and the validations.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access message body within handler then you may use following code block and access message body.

```
SOAPEnvelope env = messageContext.getEnvelope();
 if (env != null) {
        SOAPBody soapbody = env.getBody();
 }
```

Also if you need to build message then you can do that as well.

Add following dependency to your handler implementation project

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
       <artifactId>synapse-nhttp-transport</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Then import RelayUtils to handler as follows.

```
import org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils;
```

Then build message before process message body as follows(add try catch blocks when needed).

```
RelayUtils.buildMessage(((Axis2MessageContext)messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext());
```

Then you will be able to access message body as follows.

```
<soapenv:Body><test>sanjeewa</test></soapenv:Body>
```